# file_put_content array structure does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to move an array into a .json file and then simply console.log it. I think its my structure in my array that is messing it up.

```
$jsonarray = array('Symbol'=>[$symbol],'PERatio'=>[$peratio], 'MarketCap'=>[$marketcap], 'Dividend'=>[$dividend], 'ROE'=>[$roe], 'DebtToEbitda'=>[$debttoebitda], 'EbitdaGrowth' =>[$ebitdagrowth],  'RevenueGrowth' =>[$revenuegrowth],);
file_put_contents('Stockdata1.json', json_encode($jsonarray), FILE_APPEND);
```

This is how it looks like in the .json file.

```
{"Symbol":["A"],"PERatio":["31.55"],"MarketCap":["19722.500"],"Dividend":["0.87"],"ROE":["14.48"],"DebtToEbitda":["2.04"],"EbitdaGrowth":["5.40"],"RevenueGrowth":["4.20"]}{"Symbol":["AA"],"PERatio":["44.45"],"MarketCap":["6960.660"],"Dividend":["0.00"],"ROE":["2.33"],"DebtToEbitda":["0.95"],"EbitdaGrowth":["0.00"],"RevenueGrowth":["0.00"]}{"Symbol":["AAC"],"PERatio":["0.00"],"MarketCap":["217.730"],"Dividend":["0.00"],"ROE":["-2.76"],"DebtToEbitda":["8.71"],"EbitdaGrowth":["22.30"],"RevenueGrowth":["15.00"]}{"Symbol":["AAP"],"PERatio":["18.68"],"MarketCap":["6888.440"],"Dividend":["0.26"],"ROE":["12.69"],"DebtToEbitda":["1.17"],"EbitdaGrowth":["6.50"],"RevenueGrowth":["13.60"]}
```

when i then try to console.log in js like this

```
    $.getJSON('Stockdata1.json', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
    });
```

nothing comes out... Hope someone can see my mistake..

Comment: Did you check the file? Did you check the request itself? Help us help you..

Comment: Yes i checked it and nothing comes out. Only if i have one array in there like this {"Symbol":["A"],"PERatio":["31.55"],"MarketCap":["19722.500"],"Dividend":["0.87"],"ROE":["14.48"],"DebtToEbitda":["2.04"],"EbitdaGrowth":["5.40"],"RevenueGrowth":["4.20"]}

Comment: If in the browser address bar you replace the "index.php" (or whatever the page file is called) with "Stockdata1.json", what do you get? There might be an issue with spelling, or location, or access rights.

Comment: I can see the file under Network when i inspect the browser...

Comment: Your JSON output is incorrect. There are actually 2 objects in the JSON string. Just try to load the JSON output above as a var. It gives an error. It shows you exactly where you go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you `FILE_APPEND` the second array, you're invalidating the JSON in the file. The file will contain two JSON objects without a separator (i.e. (abbreviated for clarity) `{"Symbol":["A"]}{"Symbol":["B"]}`).

Instead, what you need for valid JSON, is to have the file contain a JSON array of all objects: `[{"Symbol":["A"]},{"Symbol":["B"]}]`. The only way to do that, is to not use `file_put_contents()` with the `FILE_APPEND` flag, but to load the file as JSON, add the new object, and write the full JSON back to the file.

My suggestion is to change your code to something along these lines:

```
$jsonarray = array('Symbol'=>[$symbol],'PERatio'=>[$peratio], 'MarketCap'=>[$marketcap], 'Dividend'=>[$dividend], 'ROE'=>[$roe], 'DebtToEbitda'=>[$debttoebitda], 'EbitdaGrowth' =>[$ebitdagrowth],  'RevenueGrowth' =>[$revenuegrowth],);

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('Stockdata1.json'));

if (!$data) {
    // file is empty or does not contain valid JSON
    $data = [];
} elseif (is_object($data)) {
    // file only contains a JSON object, not a JSON array
    $data = [ $data ];
}

$data[] = $jsonarray;
file_put_contents('Stockdata1.json', json_encode($data));
```